# Activity having a list and other UI

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have an activity which has an independent ImageView and a List. Earlier, I have worked with activities which were simple list activities and the code worked fine. But now I am having an error which says

> your content must have a ListView whose attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

The original code:

```
setArrayAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(partsId[position])));
```

XML:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
</ListView>
```

After some research, I came to the conclusion that may be I have to use a ListView and attach that attibute to my list. I did some change in the XML too. So revised code:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(partsId[position]));
lvParts.setAdapter(adapter);
```

XML:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
</ListView>
```

I think the reason this is happening is my Activity now has an ImageView also along with the List. Can anyone help?

Comment: share your activity codes (possible code).

Answer (score 0):

```
 android:id="@+android:id/list"
Change your listview id to above...

<ListView
    android:id="@+android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to `extends`  your class to `ListActivity` instead of `Activity`